# Asignar cookies en pedido GET con XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, firefox, cookies, http-get

Estoy tratando de asignar una cookie en una petición *GET*, en un pedido `XMLHttpRequest`.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
var pedido = new XMLHttpRequest()
pedido.open("GET","https://www.google.com/complete/search")
pedido.setRequestHeader("Cookie","SSID=AbhcxIM8JMu")
```

Esto me tira una advertencia en *Firefox*:

> El pedido de establecer un encabezado prohibido fue denegado: Cookie

Sospecho que la solución está en cambiar algo en la configuración de *Firefox*, pero no sé exactamente cómo hacerlo.

¿Es posible hacer esto en *JavaScript*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crear una cookie en JS es muy sencillo:

```
document.cookie='SSID=AbhcxIM8JMu';
```

Puedes encontrar más información en [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/DOM/document.cookie), pero realmente no hace falta mucho más: Una vez que hayas definido un valor, se añadirá automáticamente a cada petición que hagas al servidor al que pertenece la página actual.